# taking user to particular site collection on clicking webapplication url

Tags: javascript

I have 4 users who has access to 4 different site collection,when he clicks on the webapplication url he should see only the site collection that he belongs to.he wont be able to see other site collection.

Provide me the sharepoint javascript code which can be used in content editor webpart to achieve above or c# code.
it would be helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below c# code:

```
         if (SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser != null 
            && SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name.Contains("username")
            && Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("text"))
        {
            Response.Redirect(SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/_layouts/signout.aspx", true);
        }
```